# Not getting the matched value with special character in redis

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

I have this data in redis

```
{
  "data":[
    {
      "hash":[
        {
          "key":"key1",
          "values":[
            {
              "field":"DVD±R/±RW",
              "value":"Marron foncé"
            },
            {
              "field":"Two weeks",
              "value":"Deux semaines"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and here is the code

```
public Cursor<Entry<String, String>> search(final String key,
            final String hashKeyPatern) {
        final ScanOptionsBuilder buider = new ScanOptionsBuilder();
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(hashKeyPatern)) {
            buider.match(hashKeyPatern);
        }
        return hashOperations.scan(key, buider.build());
    }
```

here the key is key1
and hashKeyPatern is DVD±R/±RW

But i am not getting matching result. Same code is working for other values. I guess here the problem is '±' character. I have tried the UrlEncoder with UTF-8 encoding but it is not getting the result.

Comment: What is StringUtils? Post a minimal reproducible example as explained in the help center page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: StringUtils is the String lib and it is just checking if the hashKeyPattern is not empty :)

Comment: What String lib? Are you assuming that there is only one library with that name? Lots of projects create utility classes with similar names.